# como hacer que una transición de "height" en css haga crecer mi div solo hacia arriba?

Tags: css, css3

tengo un div al que quiero darle el efecto de crecer al pasar el ratón por encima utilizando las propiedades CSS transitions, pero no se muy bien como funciona, como lo tengo actualmente al pasar el ratón por encima del div este crece pero hacia arriba y hacia abajo, lo que quiero es que mantenga su posición y solo aumente su tamaño hacia arriba, este es mi css:

```
.calltoaction {
    position: relative;
    height: 8em;
    width: 30em;
    border: solid 2px green;
    margin-left: -30em;
    margin-top: 75vh;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 1s;
    background-color:rgba(43, 34, 68, 0.9);
}
.calltoaction:hover{
    height: 20em;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías ponerle una posición absoluta y decirle que está a `25vh` del `bottom`.

```css
.calltoaction {
    position: absolute;
    height: 8em;
    width: 30em;
    border: solid 2px green;
    margin-left: -30em;
    bottom: 25vh;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 1s;
    background-color:rgba(43, 34, 68, 0.9);
}
.calltoaction:hover{
    height: 20em;

}
```

```html
<div class="calltoaction"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La clave esta en los siguiente:

### Posicion Absoluta o fixed

Si tienes un elemento que se posiciona siempre en la parte de abajo lo mejor es usar `position: fixed` y modificar su posición en los ejes X y Y. Esto hace que el contenido posicionado siempre se mantenga en la misma posición con respecto a la ventana sin importar el scroll.

Ahora si quieres que se mantenga en una posición absoluta con respecto a un contenedor padre o el body, puedes usar `position: absolute;`, pero este contenido no te seguira con el scroll.

Para modificar el eje X y Y, puedes usar las propiedades `left; right; top; y bottom`, entonces en tu caso para que quede abajo, podemos colocarle esto al div:

```
.calltoaction{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

De esa manera, la base siempre será la parte de abajo con bottom y crecera hacia arriba. Ejemplo:

```css
.calltoaction {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8em;
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 30em;
  border: solid 2px green;
  background-color:rgba(43, 34, 68, 0.9);
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 1em;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
.calltoaction:hover{
  height: 16em;
}
```

```html
texto por defecto <br>

<div class="calltoaction">
  Contenedor que crece en hover
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaria evitar el tema de posiciones absolutas, con un contenedor con display flex, solucionas de una forma muy simple tu problema. Flex tiene la posibilidad de alinear los elemento a la parte baja de un elemento html, "align-items: flex-end;" aplicando esto al padre, el hijo se alinea abajo, y crece hacia arriba al hacer el :hover. te adjunto enlace para que veas la idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/shezn7L9/6/